# How to set auto height of the date,year etc row in dhtmlx gantt chart

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I have some custom date,month etc.. row in dhtmlx gantt chart.I want to set fix height for each row.I mean if I add or remove rows also, the height should not depend with parent height.It should be constant.For example - if I add 10 rows also,height of each individual rows should be constant, but its keep decreasing to fit into the parent height. Here is the code below

### HTML/JAVASCRIPT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.css'>
  <script src='http://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.js'></script>
  <style>
    .gantt_custom_button {
      background-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
      position: absolute;
      right: -10px;
      top: 5px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 26px;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  </style>


</head>
<div id='gantt_here' style='width:100%; height:500px;'></div>

<body>
  <script>
    var task1 = {
      'data': [{
          'id': 1,
          'text': 'Project #1',
          'start_date': '01-04-2019',
          'duration': 2,
          'order': 10,
          'progress': 0.4,
          'open': true
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'text': 'Task #1',
          'start_date': '02-04-2019',
          'duration': 1,
          'order': 10,
          'progress': 0.6,
          'parent': 1
        },
        {
          'id': 3,
          'text': 'Task #2',
          'start_date': '03-04-2019',
          'duration': 2,
          'order': 20,
          'progress': 0.6,
          'parent': 1
        },
        {
          'id': 4,
          'text': 'Task #3',
          'start_date': '05-04-2019',
          'duration': 1,
          'order': 10,
          'progress': 0.6,
          'parent': 1
        }

      ],
      'links': [{
          'id': 1,
          'source': 1,
          'target': 2,
          'type': '1'
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'source': 2,
          'target': 3,
          'type': '0'
        },
        {
          'id': 3,
          'source': 3,
          'target': 4,
          'type': '0'
        },
        {
          'id': 4,
          'source': 2,
          'target': 5,
          'type': '2'
        }
      ]
    };
    
    
    gantt.config['scales'] = [{
      unit: 'day',
      step: 1,
      format: '%d %M'
    },
    {unit: "year", step: 1, format: "%Y"},
    {unit: "month", step: 1, format: "%M"},
    {unit: "month", step: 1, format: "%M"},
    {unit: "month", step: 1, format: "%M"}
   //{unit: "month", step: 3, format: monthScaleTemplate},
    ];
    gantt.config.scale_height = 100; 
    
   
    gantt.init('gantt_here');
    gantt.parse(task1);
  </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the task row height is not changing regardless of the number of tasks in the chart. And there is built-in functionality to dynamically change the height.

You can see how it works in the snippet:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/664877d50

If that doesn't help you, please, add your configuration in the snippet above and make sure that the issue is reproduced there.
Then, click on the `Share` button and send me the link.
Or send me a ready demo with all the necessary Javascript and CSS files so that I can reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: I have added more rows above date , like in our project number of rows can be less or more,it will dynamically. After adding/removing  rows the height of each rows should not be less, it should be constant, instead chart part can go down or any scroll also fine, Link - http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/e0b6b3a41

Comment: Thank you for sending the snippet, now it is clear that you mean the timeline scales' height. You can hardcode the height via CSS.
Here is the snippet:
http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/3b2303ccc

If you want to have a fixed height with any number of rows, you need to dynamically calculate the height of the parent scale element:
http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/f9f42e0af